Node Environment Variable Is Undefined For Express Server but Defined In Vite React Front End
I have a .env file in the root directory of a react vite project. Next to it I have two folders, one for an index.js that is an express server and one that is a src folder for my front end components. In my App.jsx component, I can easily access an environment variable in that .env file with
import.meta.env.VITE_MY_API_KEY. I don't even need to import anything at the top of the component, it just works.
However, in  my server/index.js file, it just doesn't seem to recognize the environment variable I want.
I started off with my code in index.js looking like this:
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
console.log(process.env);

This seems to print my actual computer system variables. Things like my PATH, HOME, things like that. So I try this, to try and see if I can log my variable: console.log(process.env.VITE_MY_API_KEY) and I get undefined printed to the console.
Because this is a Vite project, I also tried it the Vite way. This way works on my frontend, but when I try either  console.log(import.meta.env); or console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_MY_API_KEY);, I get undefined for both.
I'm expecting an API key to be printed to the console. What could be going on here?

It would be helpful to provide an image of your folders/directory structure for easier debugging, could be also be your configuration, so details about your config files for both apps too
